# Unable to find print composer on QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, maps

Anyone have information about where Print Composer is hiding.

I have followed the instructions on the QGIS website which says it is under Projects or the button in the control panel. Neither option is there. I also don't have a File button which it says is another option.

I use QGIS 3.16 version.

[image]

Comment: Go to `New Print layout...` - the Print Composer is hiding there ;-)

Comment: Which tutorial page exactly says that?

Answer (score 3):

```
New Print Layout...
```

This creates a print composer.